# Local installation of .rpms using YUM

Tags: centos, software-installation, yum, rpm

I'm asking this question cautiously because I don't want to get this wrong.

I have a program_name.rpm file saved locally on my server (CentOS 6.5).

I have installed it previously just by navigating to it and using yum install program_name.rpm which worked fine but it didn't give me any option to specify where it is installed.

Is it possible to install this rpm to /opt/some_directory instead of it's default install location?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use rpm

```
rpm -ivh package.rpm
```

If you want to install it on different place use:

```
rpm -ivh -r /new/path package.rpm
```

but be aware under new root will be recreated the directory structure from package

Comment: this worked great, I don't suppose there is a YUM equivalent?

Comment: To clarify: yum is wrapper around rpm. rpm is the main program to manage packaged in RHEL, SuSE, CentOS and other distributions

Comment: Oh I always thought yum was based on rpm, never realized it was a wrapper, thanks for all your help

Comment: Do you have to be root to run this command?

Comment: Correct, you must be root to run the command

Answer (score 108):

Too bad you accepted that rpm answer.  That will lead to warnings from subsequent executions of yum, such as
`Warning: RPMDB altered outside of yum`

Instead you should use `yum localinstall`, per section 13 of the *Yum and RPM Tricks* page of the CentOS wiki => https://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/YumAndRPM#head-3c061f4a180e5bc90b7f599c4e0aebdb2d5fc7f6

You can use the `--installroot` option to specify a different installation root.

Comment: I do like doing things according to best practices and this answer includes the yum equivalent that I was hoping for. Unfortunately I've installed a whole bunch of packages using the rpm -ivh method already. I wish it were possible to accept two correct answers because I feel the accepted answer is correct but people coming to view this question would benefit more from this answer

Comment: Is better to use yum instead of rpm,but to solve the "warning: RPMDB altered outside of yum" is possible to use "yum history sync"

Comment: This works. When I tried just running rpm it didn't go get the dependencies. It just errored with "Failed dependencies".

Comment: "yum --nogpgcheck localinstall packagename.arch.rpm"