# Installing Octave Dependencies on CentOS 6 using yum

Tags: centos, yum, rpm

I am trying to install Octave 4.0.0 (from source) locally in my home directory on a CentOS 6 cluster.  This is a rather extensive install (see [list](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/External-Packages.html#External-Packages) of dependencies).

I have several issues :

1. From the documentation it is unclear what versions of the dependencies are necessary.  This is a nightmare b/c I find it extremely unlikely for Octave to not depend on the versions of the 20+ dependencies. Is there a way to get this via yum or some other source?
2. I am not a root user, so whenever I try to use the yum utilities to [download](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/10154) and [install](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183063/local-installation-of-rpms-using-yum) the rpm files it demands root access.  I was wondering if there is a way for me to take advantage of `yum-builddep` (without being root) to do a local install of the dependencies?
3. It appears that `yum` no longer can find octave. I'm fairly sure that I was able to find it via `yum search octave` last week. Where can I find old yum repositories?

Answer (score 1):

> It appears that yum no longer can find octave. I'm fairly sure that I was able to find it via yum search octave last week. Where can I find old yum repositories?

The `octave` package is available through the [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repository for CentOS.  The easiest way to set this up is:

```
# yum install epel-release
```

But you can also follow the instructions on the linked web page.  Once you have the EPEL repository available:

```
# yum info octave
Name        : octave
Arch        : x86_64
Epoch       : 6
Version     : 3.4.3
Release     : 1.el6
Size        : 9.1 M
Repo        : epel
Summary     : A high-level language for numerical computations
URL         : http://www.octave.org
License     : GPLv3+
```

Unfortunately...

> I am not a root user, so whenever I try to use the yum utilities to download and install the rpm files it demands root access. I was wondering if there is a way for me to take advantage of yum-builddep (without being root) to do a local install of the dependencies?

I think you're going to be mostly out of luck here.  Packaging systems like `yum` really aren't designed to work when run by an unprivileged user.  You could maybe:

```
repoquery --requires octave |
xargs -iDEP repoquery --whatprovides "DEP" |
sort -u |
grep x86_64 |
xargs yumdownloader
```

This would download all the dependencies (several of these commands come from the `yum-utils` package, so that needs to be installed).  You would get multiple versions of some packages, so you would want to prune old versions:

```
repomanage --keep=1 --old . | xargs rm
```

And now you have all the dependencies.  As I said, yum doesn't have any provision for "installing" these as an unprivileged user, but you could unpack them all into a local directory tree using `rpm2cpio`:

```
for file in *.rpm; do rpm2cpio $file | cpio -id; done
```

..but to use this you would need to muck around with compiler flags and possibly even runtime configuration like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.